# JQ: maximum file path length (windows)

Tags: windows, jq

i use jq (1.5) in a Windows 10 Environment for some json transformation operation (to load data from api to a SQL Server).
I checked yesterday a new copy of the jq transform command on my test enviroment and run in the morning in a exception (jq command, source and Destination files are identical). The different between the old and the new one is the filepath:

Old: C:\Import\

New: C:\Import\Test20170725\

Following command (in powershell) is used:

```
jq.exe -f C:\Import\Test20170725\jqfilter_cruises.jq C:\Import\Test20170725\Dreamlines_cruises.json | out-file -encoding UTF8 -filepath C:\Import\Test20170725\import_cruises.json
```

I experimented today and it looks like that the path from the input files is limited in the maximum length. If i reduce the filepath there the command works fine (like the original one). Any tips?

Regards
Timo

Comment: IIRC this bug was fixed (in September 2015) in `master`.  Can you try a more recent version than 1.5?

Comment: Hi Peak, how can i compile the master for Windows?

Comment: As I understand it, one can either go down the
Cygwin/MinGW/MinGW-64 path, or cross-compile.
Regarding the latter, see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cross-compilation.  You could plead your case at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1352

Comment: Hi Peak, i downloaded the compiled jq.exe from an example link there. Works. Hopefully there will be a official release for that in the next month. The released 1.5 Version ist a Little bit "old". Regards Timo

Comment: Where (or what) is the link you used?

Comment: Hi Peak, there is a link to a tested 1.5+ test of the master branch: [link](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/stedolan/jq/build/1.0.88). There are two versions (32/64 bit) test and under artifacts are there the compiled jq.exe's

Comment: Thanks.  The Installation page on the jq wiki now has a section on Appveyor: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in jq 1.5. jq 1.6 no longer has this problem. Please upgrade your jq installation.